# Rewriting mysql_* with PDO (table-like content)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So I'm having a bit of trouble migrating from **mysql_*** functions to PDO-like statements. I have a table in which I output a different column for each row. However, I'm unsure as to how I could achieve this with PDO.

```
        $SQL = "SELECT `id`, `email`, `information`, `type`, `language`, `status` FROM `requests`";
        $exec = mysql_query($SQL, $link);
           while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($exec)){
              echo "<tr class='tg-031e'>";
              echo "<td class='tg-031e'><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' value=" . $row['id'] . "></form></td>";
              echo "<td class='tg-031e'>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
              echo "<td class='tg-031e'><textarea readonly style='width:470px;height:80px;border:none;resize:none'>" . $row['information'] . "</textarea></td>";
              echo "<td class='tg-031e'>" . $row['type'] . "</td>";
              echo "<td class='tg-031e'>" . $row['language'] . "</td>";
              if(isset($_POST['checkbox'])){
                foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $update_id){
                  $update_id = (int)$update_id;
                  $qR = "UPDATE requests SET status='✔' WHERE id=$update_id";
                  mysql_query($qR);
                                    header('Refresh: 1; URL=index.php');
                }
              }
        }
```

For example, how do I fetch everything from the `type` column in PDO?

```
echo "<td class='tg-031e'>" . $row['type'] . "</td>";
```

Comment: [`fetch()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)

Answer (score 0):

Simple db class to get started:

```
<?php 


class db {

    public static $db_host = "";
    public static $db_user = "";
    public static $db_pass = "";
    public static $db_name = "";

    public static function dbFactory() {
        $host = self::$db_host;
        if(strpos($host,":") !==false) {
            $parts = explode(":",$host);
            $hostname = "unix_socket=".$parts[1];
        } else {
            $hostname = "host=$host";
        }
        $user = self::$db_user;
        $pass = self::$db_pass;
        $dbase = self::$db_name;        
        $pdo = new PDO("mysql:$hostname;dbname=$dbase", $user, $pass);
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);        
        return $pdo;
    }
}

$id = 115;

$pdo = db::dbFactory();
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `tablename` WHERE `id` = :id ");
$stmt->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
$res = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

print_r($res);
```

Comment: Sorry, how does this relate to the question?

Comment: @schmitsz the above code gives the OP an example how to getting started with pdo and fetch an array of arrays with the results of the query. It seems to be the case that it can give the OP an idea how to rewrite his code. Maybe i misunderstood something but in given example the OP did a `fetch_array`. I show him a way to fetch all results to an array with pdo. This can be used to rewrite the given code.